# Can a tenant resource be shared with a different (B2C) tenant user after authenticating?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to give a B2C tenant (b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com) access to a function app that sits in my main subscription tenant (e.g. company.com).

So if a user is authenticated with a B2C tenant (b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com) how can I give him authorization to use a resource at a different tenant (company.com)?

I tried giving an App in the B2C tenant (b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com) permissions to resources of the company.com tenant but the APIs or resources of company.com don't show as available to add permissions for the B2C app.

EDIT: Edited with settings and error results trying @Jas Suri - MSFT guidance:

Unable to resolve snapshot:
[image]

I get Issuer URL from B2C user flow->Run User Flow which opens and at the top shows a link that if followed shows Issuer URL https://XXX.b2clogin.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_XXX_userflow
[image]

But I also tried but got the same error with Issuer URL as you said using the URL from B2C user flow->Run User Flow URL at the top: https://XXX.b2clogin.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_xxx_userflow

The Error message at Identity Provider is "Application with ID [weapi in B2C tenant] not found in the current tenant. Tenant ID: [ID of Contoso tenant]" and makes sense because the webapi is in the B2C tenant, not in Contoso

I can't use Authentication (Classic), it's stuck and won't let me use it, can only go back to Authentication:
[image]

There is no "Disable" option in the Authentication blade, only to allow unauthenticated access. I do this but I still can't use Authentication Classic and shows the same message as before - This app is configured using the new authentication experience. Click here to access Authentication (preview).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**B2C tenant:**
1.1. Create Application Registration for your Web App
1.2. Create Application Registration for your Web API (Function App)
1.3. Expose a scope on the Web API App reg
1.4. Add a permission to the Web App App reg for the scope in (3). **Grant Admin Consent**.
1.5. Open the "Run Now" link of your AAD B2C User Flow/Custom Policy and note the   `/.well-known/openid-config` URL at the top of the blade

**Contoso tenant:**
2.1. Create your Function App
2.2. Configure it with AAD Authentication
2.3. Use Advanced authentication option
2.4. Enter the clientId from [1.1]
2.5. Enter the Issuer URL as the value from [1.5]

The Azure Function will only accept tokens from one single AAD B2C User Flow [1.5] authenticated through the Web App from [1.1].

Comment: Thanks I tried this before and I get error when I Edit the Identity Provided I've added to authentication: "App registration: Unable to resolve app registration name from registered application ID" and "Supported account types
Unable to resolve account type information from registered application ID". What do you mean used "Advanced"authentication option: Portal shows Authentication and Authentication (classic) for a function app. I selected Authentication->Add Provider->Identity Provier->Microsoft->Provie Details Existing App->Entered client id[1.1]->enter Issuer URL->audience left empty.

Comment: The Error message at Identity Provider is Application with ID [weapi in B2C tenant] not found in the current tenant. Tenant ID: [ID of Contoso tenant] and makes sense because the webapi is in the B2C tenant, not in Contoso

Comment: Try - Authentication (Classic) -> Azure AD -> Advanced

Comment: It doesn't let me, when I enter Authentication (Classic) it says "This app is configured using the new authentication experience.". And there are no other options, I can't - see snapshot above

Comment: Disable the authentication in the other blade then try classic.

Comment: I don't see a Disable option in the Authentication blade, only to allow unauthenticated access. I do this but I still can't use Authentication Classic and shows the same message as before - This app is configured using the new authentication experience. Click here to access Authentication (preview). Please see snapshot above.